# Finding the diagonals of a rhombus

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

[image]

The above diagram is of a rhombus. If $\bar{CD}=12$ and $\bar{AM}=4.5$, what is the area of the rhombus?

One of the options given for this question was "not enough information to find the answer", and this is what was marked as correct.

The diagonals of a rhombus bisect each other at right angles. This means that $\angle AMD$ is 90 degrees and that $\triangle AMD$ is a right triangle.
In addition, all sides of a rhombus are equal and so $\bar{AD}=12$.
I can use the pythagorean theorem to find the length of $\bar{MD}$. $$\sqrt{12^2-4.5^2}=11.12=\bar{MD}$$
Because the diagonals bisect each other, I can double $\bar{AM}$ to find $\bar{AC}$ and double $\bar{MD}$ to find $\bar{BD}$.
$\bar{AC}=9$ $\bar{BD}=22.24$

Now, using the formula for the area of a rhombus, I will multiply my diagonals and divide the result by two - giving me an area of $100.08$.

Is this not the correct solution?
Am I misunderstanding something about the diagonals of a rhombus?

Comment: Does that question explicitly state the figure is a rhombus? If yes, then your  answer is correct (up to some rounding error in your area, should be $\frac{27\sqrt{55}}{2} \approx 100.\color{red}{12}$).

Comment: Yes, the problem specifies it is a rhombus. THanks you @achillehui